# How to use liquid variables in php?

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

I am building a Shopify app in PHP. for that I am using an app proxy page.

where i want to use {{ customer.id }} as PHP variable.

I am using `header('Content-Type: application/liquid');` in header.

So I am able to convert

`$customer_id = '{{ customer.id }}';`

but something went wrong I am not able to get a response from API with this.

please help

Comment: Please explain exactly what happens. Do you get an error, a wrong result...??  Please also post the relevant code.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/phpish/shopify library

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught phpish\shopify\ApiException: [400] Bad Request (https://winelivetest.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-01/customers/4608718733484.json) in /var/www/vhost/data.grazitti.com/html/wineclub_cardsave/cardsave_proxy.php on line 22 thrown in /var/www/vhost/data.grazitti.com/html/wineclub_cardsave/vendor/phpish/shopify/shopify.php on line 67

Comment: $customer_id = '{{ customer.id }}';
        $customer_data =  $shopify('GET /admin/api/2021-01/customers/'.$customer_id.'.json');
        echo 'customer_data:';json_encode($customer_data);

Comment: did you try to test  your API call  only? Just enter it into the address line of a browser and see what happens?    --- GET /admin/api/2021-01/customers/'.$customer_id.'.json') ---

Comment: {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}   -----  Can it be that you simply do not give your script the correct credentials or API key to be able to get a response?

Comment: credentials are correct..

Comment: if i use $customer_id = {{customer.id}}
i am getting this error
but if i use $customer_id = 'static integer customer id'
api works

Comment: Hi, can you add the whole liquid file you're sending to Shopify ?

Comment: Simply access the proxy URL with AJAX call and send the desired data into parameters and get to easily.

Comment: is there anywhy i can accesss this in php directly without use of js